# Swift completion block with success and failure handler

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, completion

I'm working on a Swift app's login process and I'd like to know if I should include both success and failure handlers to the function, which checks if the user has successfully logged in or not.

What I want to do here is trigger the successCompletion() block only when the user successfully logged in and otherwise display an Alert with a message.
I feel the login function takes multiple arguments, and I think it is kind of hard to figure out it handles two completion handlers from LoginViewController. So, should I include both error and success handlers in the function or better to separate them somehow?

In my LoginViewController,

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    private let loginView = LoginView()

    @objc func loginButtonAction() {
        let idInputValue = loginView.loginIdTextField.text!
        let passInputValue = loginView.passwordTextField.text!
        
        LoginAPI().login(with: idInputValue, and: passInputValue, errorCompletion: show(message:)) { _ in
            let sceneDelegate = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as! SceneDelegate
            sceneDelegate.setRootVC(to: HomeViewController())
        }

    func showAlert(message: String) {
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: Alert.ButtonTitle.ok, style: .default, handler: nil)
        showAlert(title: Alert.Title.loginError, message: message, actions: [okAction], style: .alert)
    }

}
```

and my LoginAPI class,

```
import Alamofire
class LoginAPI {
    
    static var accountInfo: AccountInfo?
    private let loginEndpoint = "https://example.com"
    
    func login(with id: String, and password: String, errorCompletion: @escaping (_ m: String) -> Void?, successCompletion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let parameter: [String: Any] = ["id": id, "password": password]
        
        AF.request(loginEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: parameter)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                guard let data = response.data else {
                    errorCompletion(response.error)
                    return
                }
                
                let decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                var accountInfo: AccountInfo?
                
                do {
                    accountInfo = try decoder.decode(AccountInfo.self, from: data)
                } catch {
                    errorCompletion(error)
                }
               
                LoginAPI.accountInfo = accountInfo
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    successCompletion()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

---

updated the function

```
func login(with id: String, and password: String, completed: @escaping (Result<AccountInfo, LoginError>) -> Void) {
    
    let parameter: [String: Any] = ["id": id, "password": password]
    AF.request(loginEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: parameter)
        .responseDecodable(of: AccountInfo.self) { response in

            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(let data):
                completed(.success(data))
            case .failure(let error):
                completed(.failure(.test))
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest the [Result](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) type.

Comment: Use `result` but also, don't use `responseJSON()` (it's deprecated) that call JSONSerialization, so you are serializaing for nothing with it. Use the `responseDecodable()` directly with `AccountInfo.self`

Comment: @Larme
So if the responseDecodable() fails to decode the data, is it gonna trigger the .failure case in the next switch case (the updated function)?

Comment: You can try it by instead of writing `.responseDecodable(of: AccountInfo.self)`, but another Codable struct that has nothing to do with it: `.responseDecodable(of: AnotherDecodableStructThatWillFailToDecode.self)` And print `error` ;)

Comment: @Larme Ahh, so true!
Yeah, the .failure case is triggerd. Thank you for teaching me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common to [use `Result`](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/result-enum-type/).  By returning the result you keep the responsibility of `login()` tight and handle the result somewhere else.  And it indeed also avoids the unclarity of two completion blocks.

Other remarks: You don't need `DispatchQueue.main.async` because `AF.request` completion block is already on the main thread.

Comment: Alamofire completion handlers are on the main queue by default, so there's no need for the call to main in any case.

Comment: @JonShier Haven't used AF for a while, but indeed.  I was triggered by seeing one completion explicitly run on main, but not the other.